# Storing passwords in database to be used later

Tags: sql-server, database, passwords

I am developing a system to automatically do some processes that require a password to access. How can I store the password in the database in order for the code to use it to connect to the resources needed.

I am NOT talking about storing user passwords (I would just hash the passwords then), I need this password to be recoverable as plain text. Should I use some kind of encryption? What is the best method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EncryptByPassPhrase()` and `DecryptByPassPhrase()`

**Just for example**

```
declare @encrypt varbinary(100) 
select @encrypt = EncryptByPassPhrase('mysecretkey', 'abc' )

select @encrypt 
      ,convert(varchar(100),DecryptByPassPhrase('mysecretkey', @encrypt ))
```